# Get all the products from A which either are not present in B or have stock = 0 in B

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you please help me frame a single query to get products for below scenario -
Two Tables - Table_A (Products) and Table_B (Products and Stock)
I need to get all the products from table A which either are not present in Table B, or if they are present in B, they have stock = 0 in B.

Following is what i've tried -

```
SELECT PROD_ID FROM TABLE_A
WHERE PROD_ID NOT IN (SELECT PROD_ID FROM TABLE_B)
OR PROD_ID IN (SELECT PROD_ID FROM TABLE_B WHERE STOCK = 0)
```

This query runs forever, so I'm not sure if it gives the correct output. If it is correct, I would find ways to optimise the performance.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @jarlh I've added the query to my question. Kindly help.

Comment: Search for LEFT JOIN

Comment: What do you want the result to be if a product is present in table B, but has NULL in the STOCK column? Or is the STOCK column constrained to be NOT NULL?

Comment: @mathguy, the stock column is constrained to be NOT NULL. Anyways, I only want the product in my output which has either an entry in TABLE_B with stock value as zero or no entry at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of the query below should work.

```
select prod_id
from   table_a
where  prod_id not in (select prod_id from table_b where stock > 0)
;
```

This assumes that `prod_id` is constrained to NOT NULL in `table_b`.

Comment: it also assumes that stock can't be negative, which may or may not be a valid assumption...

Comment: @Boneist - actually, technically (using the technical definition of "stock"), no, the stock can't be negative. Of course, the OP's business may use the term in a non-technical way, but I doubt it.

Comment: Hi @mathguy, Could you please explain how this works ? Table_B has numerous products with stock > 0. So the condition inside 'not exists()' will always be true.

Comment: @mathguy I've learnt never to assume anything unless it's explicitly stated by the OP; invariably what seems like common sense to me isn't always as common as I think it should be! *{;-)

Comment: Thanks @mathguy , Worked like a charm. Didnt expect it to be that straightforward. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RajatSolanki - the "not exists" was wrong, I think I edited (to the correct version) while you were typing your question! I assume the correct version is not difficult to follow, right?

Comment: Yeah @mathguy , i'm using the query from your current version of the answer. Not difficult to follow at all and works real good. Thanks